# Index of a vector field defined with local coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry

I do not understand the definition of the index of singular point of a vector field from my textbook. The index is defined as

$I(p) = \frac{1}{2\pi} (\alpha(b) - \alpha(a))$
where
p is the singular point of vector field V,
$\gamma(t): [a,b] - > S $  is a closed curve around p on surface S with map $\sigma$,  $\alpha$ is the angle between $V(t)$ and the local $\sigma_u(t)$ coordinate along $\gamma$, the values of $\sigma_u$ and V taken at $\gamma(t)$

Let us take a vector field on sphere heading south along longitudes, it has a singular point at north pole with index 1, however V and $\sigma_{\theta}$ are at constant angle  $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as we move along a latitude rounding the north pole. I miss something about the local coordinates on  a surface here. For the vector fields on $R^2$ the the coordinate [0,1] is 'fixed' and only V rotates.